# Why does my DB2 silent/unattended Install instead invokes DB2 Install wizard and GUI. Can someone help on ths issue?

Tags: db2, installation

I want to install DB2 10.5.6 DPF on my VMWare windows machine. I manually created the response files (both the server.rsp and addpart.rsp files).

When it came time to perform the server install, I issued the following on the DB2 command line: ./db2setup -l db2server_installlog.txt  -t db2server_installtrace.txt  -r db2server.rsp

What happened is that instead of the above command installing DB2 silently and unattended, the DB2 Install wizard and the attendant GUI is invoked and I am invited to make the very same choices that produced the the response files that I am trying to use in the first place!!

Can anyone help explain the strange behavior that I have on my hand? I have installed DB2 unattended with response files before now with no issues. The difference with this install is that I am trying to see if I can install DB2 with Data Partitioning Feature on a trial basis for educational purposes only. Could not having a valid license or officially endorsed trial DB2 DPF version be the cause of the weird install behavior?

Any and all assistance will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Okonita

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the wizard to install DB2 at least on the primary partition/system of the partitioned database system. See [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/t0023605.html?lang=en) for the instructions. Thereafter you can use a response file to set up the other partitions. The [steps for using a response file](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/t0008425.html) mention as a requirement that the primary computer has been set up using the wizard.